# updating a Point's location in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a function

```
insertPoint(pt Point),
```

In the function, I would like to change the value of pt, i.e. in the function let,

```
pt.x:=pt.x+1.0
```

This doesn't work.  I've tried lots of things but no luck.  The docs suggest using update.  I've tried:

```
        UPDATE POINT SET pt[0] = 2.0*pt.x;
```

Again, no luck.

Can someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL's `point` is not a complex type, so you can't access and/or set its coordinates with fields like `point.x` / `point.y`.

Instead, you can access them with subscripts, like arrays: `point[0]` & `point[1]`:

```
UPDATE <table> SET pt[0] = 2.0 * pt[0];
```

In PL/pgSQL:

```
pt[0] := pt[0] + 1.0;
```

Alternatively, you can use the `point(double precision, double precision)` constructor, to create new `point` instances:

```
UPDATE <table> SET pt = point(2.0 * pt[0], pt[1]);
```

In PL/pgSQL:

```
pt := point(pt[0] + 1.0, pt[1]);
```

You can access *members* of `lseg` (line segment) & `box` similarly (though it's undocumented), but it's not allowed with other geometry types: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/4163).